# Can I resume my program after Tcl_Main() finishes

Tags: tcl

I start interactive tcl interpreter by calling Tcl_main() and take some tcl commands there. After that, I want to quit tcl interpreter and resume my program. However, when I type "exit", it will exit the whole program. Is there a way to exit tcl interpreter and continue my program ?  Thanks.

Comment: `exit` will end the process.

Answer (score 2):

The `Tcl_Main()` function does not provide any way for code to resume after it finishes; it's a convenience wrapper for handling simple programs so that you don't have to worry about such things, but that wrapper is limited in a number of ways, and one of those is that you can't do what you're seeking to do. (At the end of the function, it calls `Tcl_Exit()`.)

But you don't need to use `Tcl_Main()`! It just uses Tcl's public API (with a few exceptions that probably don't matter for you). You can duplicate everything by calling (approximately):

```
Tcl_FindExecutable(argv[0]); // ONCE PER PROCESS; INITIALISES TCL C LIBRARY

Tcl_Interp *interp = Tcl_CreateInterp();
// ... now in your loop evaluate code, perhaps from the user ...
Tcl_Eval(interp, "some code here");
// ... 
Tcl_DeleteInterp(interp);

// Carry on as normal
```

There's no great magic in there. Just initialise the library, create an interpreter, evaluate your code in there (perhaps after getting it from the user; invent your own reader loop if you want or code it up in Tcl), and then delete the interpreter when you're done.

Comment: I suggest that you provide your own `exit`, which sets a flag that breaks the loop and calls [`Tcl_CancelEval`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclLib/Cancel.htm).